# viewing mysql blob with putty

Tags: mysql, database, blob, putty

I am saving a serialized object to a mysql database blob.

After inserting some test objects and then trying to view the table, i am presented with lots of garbage and "PuTTYPuTTY" several times.

I believe this has something to do with character encoding and the blob containing strange characters.

I am just wanting to check and see if this is going to cause problems with my database, or if this is just a problem with putty showing the data?

Description of the QuizTable:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Type        | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment                                                                                                           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| classId     | varchar(20) | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references | FK related to the ClassTable. This way each Class in the ClassTable is associated with its quiz in the QuizTable. |
| quizId      | int(11)     | NULL              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references | This is the quiz number associated with the quiz.                                                                 |
| quizObject  | blob        | NULL              | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references | This is the actual quiz object.                                                                                   |
| quizEnabled | tinyint(1)  | NULL              | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |                                                                                                                   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

What i see when i try to view the table contents:

```
select * from QuizTable;

questionTextq ~ xp    sq ~    w
t q1a1t q1a2xt 1t q1sq ~     sq ~    w
t q2a1t q2a2t q2a3xt 2t q2xt test3 |           1 |
+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the [hex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function on blobs as well as strings. You can run a query like this.

```
Select HEX(quizObject) From QuizTable Where....
```

Comment: That helped the viewing problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Putty is reacting to what it thinks are terminal control character strings in your output stream.  These strings allow the remote host to change something about the local terminal without redrawing the entire screen, such as setting the title, positioning the cursor, clearing the screen, etc..

It just so happens that when trying to 'display' something encoded like this, that a lot of binary data ends up sending these characters.

You'll get this reaction catting binary files as well.

blob will completely ignore any character encoding settings you have.  It's really intended for storing binary objects like images or zip files.

If this field will only contain text, I'd suggest using a text field.

Comment: I am serializing the object before putting into the database, isn't blob the only data type in mysql that can hold a serialized object correctly?